# Do NSSize and NSPoint work in XCode 3.2.3 when IOS is installed?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ios

I'm seeing some weirdity and am trying to determine - environment or me ...  FWIW - I'm working through chapter 12 in Tim Isted's book.  I've double & triple checked - still getting weird results -

Comment: Yes they do. What is it that you are seeing? Please post some code.

Answer (score 2):

iOS uses Core Graphics for drawing so instead of NSPoint and NSSize you should be using CGPoint and CGSize. They are actually the same exact thing and when building for 64 bits the two are interchangeable. However the iOS frameworks don't define the NS versions. Basically try solving your problems by using CGPoint and CGSize